# SQL select result of 1 column as columns in temptable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `T1` and `T2`,

`T1` with the attributes `id pk, T2_id fk, Question`
`T2` with the attributes `id pk, QuestionResponse`

I want with a select query of question from `T1`, store the result of the query (questions)  as columns into a temp table with `QuestionResponse` as values.

Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: Also, a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) of your data would be most useful.

Comment: what have you tried till yet...please provide some code that you have executed and failed at...

Comment: Hi, I'm using sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for inserting from one table to another is:

```
insert into OneTable
(field1, field2, etc)
select field_1, field_2, etc
from OtherTables
etc
```

However you should look at what you have done so far.  It looks odd to me.

For example, you have a foreign key to the answers in your question table.  Shouldn't it be the other way around.

Also, is T2 really a temp table?

Comment: Thanks Dan,
T1 and T2 are real tables in DB, what i want is to make an temptable with columns from a select from T1 (values of T1.col1) and values for each column from T2.col2.